# Debugging an eclipse / maven project on a remote server?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty

I use my laptop for development but its resources are limited. I have a local eclipse / maven and my local codebase and I want to keep that because I want to be able to program, compile and junit-test all time.

At my office, I'd like to be able to debug in a production-like scenario, that means, with a big database and and a 8GB RAM java heap.

I thought It shouldn't be too difficult to set up eclipse and maven to put the compiled code on a remote machine, execute a maven process (jetty:run on the remote machine) and attach eclipse for debugging. The remote machine can have its own database and I only have to make sure that the maven repositories are in sync.

Did anyone manage to run this or a similar scenario? I still could not figure out **how to put the compiled sources of my ~10 projects on a remote machine**. I think running a maven task and attaching a debugger should be easy with some ssh-magic.

Comment: This can be easily done. What do you want to debug exactly? Unit tests? Embedded Jetty? Provide futher information.

Comment: Hi Micheal, as I wrote in the description I want to remote run-and-debug a mvn jetty:run java process. The CLASSPATH consists in ~10 classes folders from my eclipse workspace (maven workspace resolution enabled) and - of course - the maven dependencies (which can be located on the remote server, no magic necessary). How do you suggest to debug this environment?

Comment: After some time now I think I'll try to write some kind of java environment wrapper which "understands" the "run as maven build ..." calls. It already works for running simple java scripts on a remote host. (it copies the classpath and invokes java via ssh, connection input/outputstream). Yet, its far from beeing ready...

Answer (score 3):

No ssh-magic should really be required unless firewalls are a problem. Just get your project onto the remote somehow, and then run your build with `mvnDebug` instead of `mvn`. Maven will listen for a debug connection on port 8000 by default and will wait until you've connected to proceed with the build. Configure a [remote debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cremdbug.htm) launcher in Eclipse, and it will connect and debug like normal. As for getting the code across, you could use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), but this is an excellent use case for git. That's how I do this exact thing myself.

**Edit:** I've never looked for a way to do this with Eclipse, but you can run any arbitrary command from Eclipse, so rsync should work fine. With rsync, you'd want something like

```
rsync -ruz . <user>@<host>:/<path>
```

Run that from your project directory, and it should copy the full content of the directory to  on the remote host, only copying updated files after the initial copy. You can exclude directories, like target, with the repeatable `--exclude` option. E.g. `--exclude=target`. After copying the project, you could start a build with

```
ssh <user>@<host> mvnDebug <whatever>
```

The git way might seem a little more arcane if you aren't acquainted with git, but it has the additional benefit of being able to easily make fixes on the remote and pull them back to local. With git, you'd first log in to the remote with ssh, create a project directory, and `git init` it. AFter that, you can push changes to the remote at any time with

```
git push -f <user>@<host>:/<path> master
```

assuming you're working in master, and then on the remote:

```
git reset --hard
mvnDebug <whatever>
```

Comment: "Just get your project onto the remote somehow" is the tricky part - I mean I don't want to do it by hand but just the eclipse way - by keystroke. Although I don't have any git experiences, what I don't want is to check out my source code on a remote host.

Comment: Ryan gave you the correct solution. 1. get your code over to that machine. 2. Make it compile 3. run mvnDebug with jetty:run and attach to that VM. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well (I didn't use git, but rsync) for simple projects (one or some eclipse projects). I have troubles get the "enable workspace resolution" feature of m2eclipse working for the remote scenario but I'm working on it. I try to intercept the java incocation and copy the class folders of dependant projects to the remote host, too.